# Object(Output|Input)Stream binary protocol

Tags: java, serialization, binary, protocols, objectoutputstream

I was wondering if anyone had some resources that describe the binary protocol used by `ObjectOutputStream`. I realize of course that objects themselves can specify what their data by implementing the `Externalizable` interface, so I guess I'm looking more toward the structure of the object graph - the metadata if you will.

I am writing a C program that has to talk to a legacy Java program. I have no way to change either of these requirements so find myself reverse engineering the `ObjectOutputStream` protocol. (There is a server that uses HTTP for transport and returns Object*Stream as the HTTP response.)

However, I feel like someone else out there has to have done this work before. Can you point to any resources to speed up my work?

Comment: How are you going to talk to the Java program? Is there a server , serving the app?

Comment: You can't find this? Where did you look? Obviously the Object Serialization Specification. But in addition to Externalizable, you also have to cope with the fact that any Serializable class can define or add its own protocol via readObject(), readResolve(), writeObject(), and writeReplace(). This really makes your project quite infeasible in the general case. If you only dealing with one fixed class whose source code cannot change you might get lucky. You should really get the whole requirement reviewed. You can't practically speaking implement serialization correctly without a JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/index.html

and from there

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html

Comment: I'm indebted to you. I could not find this information! You saved me so much pain...